# Why is window not working when calling external function from closure?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

I'm trying to pass in a function to my simple tutorial code so I can trigger event on the page.

I have two javascript files: map.js and tutorial.js. Map.js in in the root and tutorial.js is in a closure because I want to be able to reuse this with no problems.

function in map.js

```
function foo(bar){
    // do something
}
```

The closure in tutorial.js. I'm just including my callFunc method, but I'm getting the $step from an element on the page which has data attributes.

```
<li data-func="foo" data-param="bar">...</li>
```

I cannot get this function to actually call. As you can see I've tried window and root.

```
(function ($, root, window) {
    // Use strict mode to reduce development errors.
    // @link http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/03/13/its-time-to-start-using-javascript-strict-mode/
    "use strict";

    /**
     * Calls function from step and passes params.
     */
    function callFunc($step) {
        var func = $step.attr("data-func");
        var param = $step.attr("data-param");
        if (func !== undefined) {
            console.log(root.func);
            if (param !== undefined) {
                window.func(param);
            } else {
                window.func();
            }
        }
    }

})(jQuery, this, window);
```

The map.js file has a function foo(bar). I want to call this from my closure for tutorial.

Comment: Why is this question getting downvotes?  I thought I provided ample information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
window.func(param);
window.func();
```

try

```
window[func](param);
window[func]();
```

Comment: I thought I had tried that and it didn't work. However, it is working now! Thanks.